# How to efficiently get TransformStamped in Eloquent?

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a `geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped` message, to send through a TransformBroadcaster.

```
void sendTransform(tf2:Transform myTf2Transform,  rclcpp::Time myTime, std::string global_frame, std::string child_frame)
{
    geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped tmp_tf_stamped;
    // ...
    tfb_->sendTransform(tmp_tf_stamped);
}
```

I tried to use `tf2::convert` to convert a `tf2::Stamped<tf2::Transform>` into `geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped`:

```
tf2::TimePoint myTimepoint; // TODO get tf2::TimePoint from rclcpp::Time
tf2::Stamped <tf2::Transform> test_stamped(myTf2Transform, myTimepoint, global_frame);
tf2::convert(test_stamped, tmp_tf_stamped);    
// /opt/ros/eloquent/include/tf2/impl/convert.h:65:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘toMsg(const tf2::Stamped<tf2::Transform>&)’
tmp_tf_stamped.child_frame_id = child_frame;
```

I then tried to create the message and just fill in its fields, converting the `tf2:Transform` into the `geometry_msgs::msg::Transform` type of the message field:

```
tmp_tf_stamped.child_frame_id = child_frame;
tmp_tf_stamped.header.frame_id = global_frame;
tmp_tf_stamped.header.stamp = myTime;

geometry_msgs::msg::Transform test_transform;
tf2::convert(latest_tf_.inverse(), test_transform); 
// /opt/ros/eloquent/include/tf2/impl/convert.h:65:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘toMsg(const tf2::Transform&)’
tmp_tf_stamped.transform = test_transform;
```

And finally I got it working by inputting each field by hand.

```
tmp_tf_stamped.child_frame_id = child_frame;
tmp_tf_stamped.header.frame_id = global_frame;
tmp_tf_stamped.header.stamp = myTime;
tmp_tf_stamped.transform.translation.x = myTf2Transform.getOrigin().x();
tmp_tf_stamped.transform.translation.y = myTf2Transform.getOrigin().y();
tmp_tf_stamped.transform.translation.z = myTf2Transform.getOrigin().z();
tmp_tf_stamped.transform.rotation.x = myTf2Transform.getRotation().x();
tmp_tf_stamped.transform.rotation.y = myTf2Transform.getRotation().y();
tmp_tf_stamped.transform.rotation.z = myTf2Transform.getRotation().z();
tmp_tf_stamped.transform.rotation.w = myTf2Transform.getRotation().w();
```

This feels quite inefficient, though. What is the recommended approach to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347582/how-to-efficiently-get-transformstamped-in-eloquent?/) by [bluemoon93](https://answers.ros.org/users/52878/bluemoon93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you include the header `tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h` that implements the templated version of those conversions?

https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/ce75a9f1ee748eddfe33d694a4a42d3767052d17/tf2_geometry_msgs/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h#L688

`geometry_msgs::TransformStamped toMsg(const tf2::Stamped<tf2::Transform>& in)`

Sorry that's meldodic, it's also in ROS 2 at: https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/72b5b179df1818a81290631cb20578e279bffcb3/tf2_geometry_msgs/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h#L510

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluemoon93](https://answers.ros.org/users/52878/bluemoon93/) on 2020-03-27**:
Yes, that works. I just have to find a way to convert rclcpp::Time to tf2:TimePoint